# How to make the notifications play a sound?

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications

I'm developing an app that sends notifications to the user with a message and a sound. There are two switches, 1 to turn on and off the notifications and the second to turn on and off the notification sound. I wrote the code for the notification sound but it doesn't seem to work.
Do you have any idea about how to make the notification sound to play when a notification pops up?

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

import java.util.Set;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;
import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
import static com.example.myevents.R.drawable.notification;


public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch simpleswitch1;
    Switch simpleswitch2;
    private Notification notification;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;
    boolean enableSound = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        simpleswitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch1);
        simpleswitch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch2);
        simpleswitch1.setChecked(false);
        simpleswitch2.setChecked(false);
        simpleswitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    int notifyID = 1;
                    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
                    CharSequence name = "channel 1";// The user-visible name of the channel.
                    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, Visitor.class);
                    intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", notifyID);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


// Create a notification and set the notification channel.
                    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Settings.this, CHANNEL_ID);
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
                    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                    notificationBuilder.setContentText("New notification");
                    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                    notificationBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID).build();
                    if (enableSound){
                        notificationBuilder.setSound(android.provider.Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
                        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,100});
                    }

                    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();





                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);


// Issue the notification.
                    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);






                }
                simpleswitch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        enableSound = isChecked;
                    }
                });






                }});}}
```

Comment: look at the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Once you have setdefault on a notificationbuilder, it will ignore subsequent calls like setsound and setvibrate.

**You have to set sound and vibration in setdefault method always.**

```
 if (shouldSound && !shouldVibrate) {
                    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
                }
                if (shouldVibrate && !shouldSound) {
                    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                            .setSound(null);
                }
                if (shouldSound && shouldVibrate) {
                    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                }
```

For a simple working example of Notifications on all versions, you can consult the following repo https://github.com/usman14/Notification

[image]